# Running chutzpah on server and in Visual Studio using different projects

Tags: jasmine, chutzpah

I'm having several projects containing my javascript sources and one project containing my javascript tests. Now I'm wondering how to set my references in the test files to make them work in Visual Studio and the automated integration build on server side. The challenge is that the file struture differs in both locations.

Locally (Visual Studio) there is the usual file structure:

```
project-a/
    content/scripts/library-x.js

tests-project/
    tests/library-x-test.js
```

I set a reference in library-test-js which looks like this and works fine in VS:

```
/// <reference path="../../project-a/content/scripts/library-x.js" />
```

On server side everything is copied to the build output folder what changes the file structure to look like this:

```
build-folder/library-x-test.js
build-folder/content/scripts/library-x.js
```

The reference in library-x-test.js doesn't work anymore there. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [chutzpah.json file](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah.json-Settings-File) to configure your file paths instead of the reference comments. The chutzpah.json file give you more control and lets you use wild cards. Path's in the chutzpah.json file are relative to the location of that file so you are sometimes able to make things work in both build and local as long as you place that file correctly.

Comment: Thank's a lot. I did not realize that I can add both the local and the server references to the same file. I expected chutzpath to break when encountering any non-existent reference. But luckily non-existent references seem to be ignored, so all references can be put in the same chutzpah.config.